Mistralai/mistral-finetune for classification task
I'm interested in using the Mistral fine-tuning package found here:
mistralai/mistral-finetune
My dataset is in CSV format with two columns: "text" (containing the text to be classified) and "label" (an integer between 0 and 3).
The documentation mentions two data file types for pre-training:
pretrain:
{"text": "Text contained in document n°1"}
instruct:
{ "messages": [ { "role": "user", "content": "User interaction n°1 contained in document n°1" }...
The pretrain format seems irrelevant for my classification task, and the instruct format doesn't seem to fit my labeled data structure.
How can I adapt my CSV data to be compatible with this fine-tuning package for a classification task? Are there any examples or specific configurations I should be aware of?
